# Calendar "whites out" the current date

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm creating an Android app for a summer module and it requires the integration of a calendar. I am able to implement the calendar, however, the current date is being whited out, and I am unable to revert it.

[image: Example]

I've tried messing around with the color attributes of the CalendarView, but have yet to be able to fix it. Additionally, is it possible for me to customize the appearance/ theme of the calendar? I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: edit: decreasing the opacity of the calendar's background color to 0, there's an opaque white circle over the current date

Comment: You should place this edit in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a theme to the calendar view like android:theme="@style/CalendarTheme",

```
 <style name="CalendarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

color accent should be the background of selected date here.
You can add any number of attributes to this theme